# weird issue with paypal payments

Tags: php, paypal

I have successfully managed to integrate paypal with a test website, including transferring of cash between different accounts.  However, unless the unit price is declared in the php file, it is immediately assumed to be 1Euro rather than the desired amount of 0.01Euros (using `$unitprice = isset($_POST['unitprice']);` )  However if I insert the unit price directly into php for example `$unitprice = 0.01;`, it works perfectly fine.

I have used this tutorial as a guideline http://www.evoluted.net/thinktank/web-development/paypal-php-integration

HTML CODE:

```
      <form id="paypal_form" class="paypal" action="payments.php" method="post" target="_blank">
         <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick" />
         <input type="hidden" name="unitprice" value="0.01" />
         <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value=""/>
         <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="MT" />
         <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR" />
         <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="BuyNowBF:btn_buynow_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest" />
<input type="text" name="first_name" value=""/>
<input type="text" name="last_name" value=""/>
<select name="quantity">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
 </select>
<input type="text" name="payer_email" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="123456"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit Payment" />
 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

PHP CODE:

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$db_name = "paypal_test";

// paypal settings 
$paypal_email = 'my email address';
$return_url = 'http://localhost/Webdevelopment/V18/paypal/success.html';
$cancel_url = 'http://localhost/Webdevelopment/V18/paypal/cancel.html';
$notify_url = 'http://localhost/Webdevelopment/V18/paypal/payments.php';

$item_name = "An Item";
$unitprice = isset($_POST['unitprice']); (0.01)
$quantity = isset($_POST['quantity']);

$item_amount = $unitprice * $quantity;
echo $item_amount;

// include functions
include ("functions.php");
...
```

NOTE: unit prices will be obtained from a database for safety reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`isset($_POST['unitprice']);` will be evaluated to `true` which would mean `1` as integer. The correct line would be:

`$unitprice = isset($_POST['unitprice'])?$_POST['unitprice']:0.01;`

(Meaning: If a unit price is set in POST, this value should be taken and 0,01 otherwise.)

Two more remarks:

- The same applies to the line below (`$quantity = ...`)
- At least in a production environment, you should always check and validate all user inputs! You could use `filter_input` and `is_numeric` in that case, together with conditions like `>0` and `<1000` or so.